# request for member 'x' in something not a structure or union and segmentation fault (lost)

Tags: c, pointers, struct, segmentation-fault, malloc

//Goal: Load data from a file into the struct

```
typedef struct {
        int year;
        char* make;
        char* model;
        int miles;
    } Car;

    void fill_garage(Car** garage, char* cars, int* size);

    int main(int argc, char** argv)
    {
        if(argc<3)
        {
            printf("Not enough arguments.\n");
            return 0;
        }

        int size;
        Car** garage;
        fill_garage(garage, argv[1], &size);

        return 0;
    }

    void fill_garage(Car** garage, char* cars, int* size)
    {
        int i;
        FILE* inputF=fopen(cars, "r");
        fscanf(inputF, "%d", size);
        garage=malloc(sizeof(Car)*(*size));
        for(i=0; i<(*size); i++)
        {
            garage[i].make=malloc(sizeof(char)*MAX_STRING_LEN);
            garage[i].model=malloc(sizeof(char)*MAX_STRING_LEN);
            //The line below causes a segmentation fault when there are no errors
            fscanf(inputF, "%d %s %s %d", &garage[i].year, garage[i].make, garage[i].model, &garage[i].miles);
        }
    }
```

//I'm not expecting anyone to just give me the corrected code (though that would be nice) If you could point be to a resource where I could learn about pointers would be great. Here's the assignment sheet if you want to see it. http://pastebin.com/LNeCx70m

Comment: Don't post code on `pastebin.com` it never loads.

Comment: The pastebin contains the assignment information. There's not much code.

Comment: this code looks very familiar...

Answer (score 1):

1. You have to pass the address of `garage` to `fill_garage()`, so this

   ```
   Car** garage;
   fill_garage(garage, argv[1], &size);
   ```

   should be

   ```
   Car *garage;
   fill_garage(&garage, argv[1], &size);
   /*          ^ pass the address of garage */
   ```
2. You don't need `malloc()` for a fixed size string, just redefine your struct like

   ```
   typedef struct {
       int  year;
       char make[MAX_STRING_LEN];
       char model[MAX_STRING_LEN];
       int  miles;
   } Car;
   ```
3. Check `fopen()` and `malloc()` returned values, if they fail both return `NULL`, if you failed to open the file, then you will cause undefined behavior. Also check the return value of `fscanf()`.
4. Include `stdio.h` for `printf()` and `fscanf()` and `stdlib.h` for `malloc()`.

I fixed your code, so it must not have any issues in principle

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_STRING_LEN 128

typedef struct {
    int  year;
    char make[MAX_STRING_LEN];
    char model[MAX_STRING_LEN];
    int  miles;
} Car;

void fill_garage(Car **garage, char *cars, int *size);

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    if (argc < 3) 
    {
        printf("Not enough arguments.\n");
        return 0;
    }

    int  size;
    Car *garage;

    fill_garage(&garage, argv[1], &size);

    return 0;
}

void fill_garage(Car **output, char *cars, int *size)
{
    int   i;
    FILE *inputF;
    Car  *garage;

    if (output == NULL)
        return;
    *output = NULL;
    inputF  = fopen(cars, "r");
    if (inputF == NULL)
        return;
    if (fscanf(inputF, "%d", size) != 1)
    {
        fclose(inputF);
        return;
    }
    garage  = malloc(sizeof(*garage) * *size);
    *output = garage;
    if (garage == NULL)
    {
        fclose(inputF);
        return;
    }
    i = 0;
    while ((i < *size) && (fscanf(inputF, "%d%127s%127s%d", &garage[i].year, garage[i].make,
                                garage[i].model, &garage[i].miles) == 4))
    {
        i += 1;
    }
}
```